# Quiero desinstalar fly.io

Tags: javascript, nodejs, docker, powershell

`iwr https://fly.io/install.ps1 -useb | iex`

Lo instalae con este comando en mi powershell

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como indican en el hilo cerrado en [el que comentaste](https://github.com/superfly/flyctl/issues/1099), todo lo que hace falta es que borres lo que está bajo el directorio

`C:\Users\tuUsuario\.fly\bin`

(que puede ser un directorio oculto, configura tu explorador para verlo)